# Separating data in different columns in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have data of different companies like names, addresses, phone numbers and emails in one column of an Excel workbook. How do I separate these columns using Excel formulas?
Here is the sample data:

```
America
Dan Wilson
Ogilvy PR Worldwide
Bingham Farms, MI: 32270 Telegraph Road,
Suite 200, Bingham Farms, MI 48025
OPRGenpact@ogilvy.com
+1 212-880-5346

India
Rudra Bose
Genesis Burson-Marsteller
Unitech Infospace, Central Park II,
Sector 48, Gurgaon, Haryana
+91 124 441 7592

Europe
Quintin Keanie
Ogilvy Public Relations
Berkshire: Vandervell House,
Vanwall Business Park, Maidenhead,
Berkshire SL6 4UB, England, United Kingdom
genpactuk@uk.ogilvypr.com
+44 207 227 5200
```

Comment: I am reasonably certain you need no formulas at all (and should just search [SU] for the way to have Excel separate columns), but in any case, without sample data it will probably be impossible to answer this.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However,I can't use text to column as the data need to be seperated into different fields such as company name, address etc.

Comment: Text-to-column is, in my experience, fairly flexible, so I have no idea what kind of data you're looking at that won't let it work.

Comment: this data is in a single column

Comment: address's have 3-5 rows

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement (eg "*in **one** column of an Excel workbook. How do I separate these column**s***") is not entirely clear to me but labelling the components and splitting the street addresses may be a start. Assuming A1 is blank, `America` is in B2 and you have a list of all possible entries (Named `LArray`) for the first of each group then in A2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,LArray,0)),"Country",IF(A1="Country","Name",IF(A1="Name","Company",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("@",B2)),"email",IF(LEFT(B2)="+","Tel:",IF(OR(A1="Company",ISNUMBER(A1)),ROW())))))))
```

Then filter on ColumnA, deselect the bottom six options, apply Text to Columns with Comma as the delimiter and remove the filter. The result should look like:

[image]